# Remote desktop protocol experience

Tags: rdp

Whats the internet bandwidth required to have **near desktop experience** while doing a RDP (Remote desktop )  to windows and linux machines ? I use NX client to login to remote linux machines and Windows RDP to windows machines.

Comment: latency is probably more important then bandwith

Comment: Depends somewhat on how fast your desktop is. :)

Comment: depends on what you include as part of the desktop experience. Viewing files while using only page up/down in Notepad, 150kb/sec is comfortable. Viewing you tube, and gigabit is marginal.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by xenny it is highly dependent on the refresh rate of the applications you are running. But for most office like desktop applications (not including video) typical usage is around 120-150kbps tops.

I can recommend reading this white paper on RDP performance by ms:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/d/9/4d9ae285-3431-4335-a86e-969e7a146d1b/RDP_Performance_WhitePaper.docx

There is also:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/03/03/top-10-rdp-protocol-misconceptions-part-1.aspx

It's been a few years since I worked with terminal server and RDP so I have very little experience with analyzing RDP performance on windows 7 and win2008R2.